# How to migrate MySQL database from Latin-1 to UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a MySQL Database (`myDB`; ~2GB in size) with 4 Tables (`tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3`, `tab4`). Currently, the data that is stored in the tables was added using the charset `ISO-8859-1` (i.e. `Latin-1`).

I'd like to **convert** the data in all tables to `UTF-8` and use `UTF-8` as default charset of the tables/database/columns.

On https://blogs.harvard.edu/djcp/2010/01/convert-mysql-database-from-latin1-to-utf8-the-right-way/ I found an interesting approach:

```
mysqldump myDB | sed -i 's/CHARSET=latin1/CHARSET=utf8/g' | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 | mysql myDB2
```

I haven't tried it yet, but are there any caveats?

**Is there a way to do it directly in the MySQL shell?**

[EDIT:]

Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages;` after running `ALTER TABLE messages CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;`

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`),
  KEY `index_user_status_date` (`user`,`status`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3285217 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to convert the tables.  But then you need to convert the application, too.

```
ALTER TABLE tab1 CONVERT TO utf8mb4;
etc.
```

To check, do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tab1`; it should show you `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Note: There are 3 things going on:

- Convert the encoding of the data in any `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` columns.
- Change the `CHARACTER SET` for such columns.
- Change the `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` for the table -- this comes into play if you add any new columns without specifying a charset.

The application...

When you connect from a client to MySQL, you need to tell it, in a app-specific way or via `SET NAMES`, the encoding of the bytes in the client.  This does *not* have to be the same as the column declarations; conversion will occur during `INSERT` and `SELECT`, if necessary.

I recommend you take a backup and/or test a copy of one of the tables.  Be sure to go all the way through -- insert, select, display, etc.

Comment: I ran `ALTER TABLE tab1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` You said that `Convert the encoding of the data in any VARCHAR and TEXT columns.` takes place during that step. This is also what I found on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-character-set . But actually **the data stored in my table was not converted** - it is still in `Latin-1` - only the defaults and the datatype of some columns was changed (I ran `diff dump_before_convert.sql dump_after_cobert.sql` on the dumps). How can I convert the data that is currently stored in `latin-1` to `utf-8mb4`?

Comment: Please show the current `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (at least for that column) and `SELECT HEX(col) ...`.  Without both of those, it is hard to say what is actually in the column, and whether or not that is OK.